# A better way to use Seq.fold in F#

Tags: f#, fold, seq

I wrote a small console app that update a Type record without using any mutable variable. If that looks simple for seasoned functional programmers, it was quite a hard work for me.
It works, but there is one thing I am not happy with. But before that, let's start with the code:

```
open System

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Type, no data validation to keep it simple
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{FirstName} {LastName} is a {Age} year old {Sex}")>]
type Student = {
   FirstName: string
   LastName : string
   Sex : char
   Age: int
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// I/O functions
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let getConsoleChar message =
   printf "\n%s" message
   Console.ReadKey().KeyChar

let getConsoleString message =
   printf "\n%s" message
   Console.ReadLine()

let getConsoleInt = getConsoleString >> Int32.Parse   //no tryparse to keep it simple, I'm sure you can type an integer

let isValidCommand command = [ 'f'; 'l'; 's'; 'a'; 'x'] |> List.contains command

let isStopCommand = (=) 'x'

let processCommand student command  =
   match command with
   | 'f' -> { student with FirstName =  (getConsoleString "First Name: ")}
   | 'l' -> { student with LastName =  (getConsoleString "Last Name: ")}
   | 's' -> { student with Sex =  (getConsoleChar "Sex: ")}
   | 'a' -> { student with Age =  (getConsoleInt "Age: ")}
   | 'x' -> student
   | _ -> failwith "You've just broken the Internet, theorically you cannot be here"


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Program
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let initialStudent = {
   FirstName = String.Empty
   LastName = String.Empty
   Sex = Char.MinValue
   Age = 0
   }

let commands = seq {
   while true do 
      yield getConsoleChar "Update [f]irst name, [l]ast name, [s]ex, [a]ge or e[x]it: " }


let finalStudent =
   commands
   |> Seq.filter isValidCommand
   |> Seq.takeWhile (not << isStopCommand)
   |> Seq.map (fun cmd -> (initialStudent, cmd))
   |> Seq.fold (fun student studentAndCommand -> processCommand student (snd studentAndCommand)) initialStudent

printfn "\n<<<< %A >>>>\n" finalStudent
```

My problem is with

```
|> Seq.map (fun cmd -> (initialStudent, cmd))
|> Seq.fold (fun student studentAndCommand -> processCommand student (snd studentAndCommand)) initialStudent
```

It looks bizarre to transform a sequence of `char` into a `Student*char` to be able to plug it with a`Seq.fold`. Also, if using the `initialStudent` as a starting point for `Seq.fold` is logical, it feel weird to use it in the mapping transformation (I'm not sure anyone would understand the logic if this code was pushed in prod).

Is there a better way to treat the sequence of commands or is this code standard and acceptable in the functional world?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get rid of the `map` and simplify the `fold` considerably:

```ml
commands
    |> Seq.filter isValidCommand
    |> Seq.takeWhile (not << isStopCommand)
    |> Seq.fold processCommand initialStudent
```

I'm not sure why you thought you had to map the `seq<char>` into a `seq<Student * char>` to begin with. Since you immediately use `snd` to extract the `char` from the tuple, undoing the map, the tuples' first elements are totally ignored. Much cleaner to simply avoid creating tuples in the first place